# Does using bitcoins require a "K-1" under some circumstances?

Tags: trading, legal

That's it...whenever currencies are traded, the possibility of a K-1 form arises, and since we're dealing with the dollar and the bitcoin here, and some people just trade the two without using them for a "pay-pal" purchase,it seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Regulation in the area of digital currencies is still emerging, the best way to approach the topic is probably to talk to a tax advisor or tax lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you must report a capital gain (or loss) when you convert the BTC back into dollars.  But I am not an accountant so you should consult your own accountant and not rely on me.